# Is there any solution for trimming the video for particular time in react-native?

Tags: react-native

I create the react native RNCamera app,i shoot the video by rncamera after that i want to trim that video while shooting the video and save the trimmed video .

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbrUO.png)

Answer (score 0):

[FFmpeg kit for react native](https://github.com/arthenica/ffmpeg-kit/tree/main/react-native) is the best way to go about doing this.

After installing FFmpeg kit to your project, you can then [follow this standard ffmpeg trimming guide](https://shotstack.io/learn/use-ffmpeg-to-trim-video/) to create the necessary command to trim the video.